# Ruby Sinatra "undefined method 'get"' when called inside a class

Tags: ruby, get, sinatra

The following code worked just fine:

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  greeting = "Hello, World!"
  return greeting
end
```

When I put it in a class, I received errors:

```
require 'rubygems' if RUBY_VERSION < '1.9'
require 'sinatra'

class Hello
  get '/' do
    greeting = "Hello, World!"
    return greeting
  end
end
```

I get the message:

```
hello.rb:5:in '<class:Hello>':undefined method 'get' for Hello:Class (NoMethodError)
        from hello.rb:4:in '<main>'
```

It doesn't work in a method, either.  Any tips on how to get this to work?  Thanks!

Comment: Try with your class being a sinatra application class Hello < Sinatra::Application

Comment: Thanks, it did compile using that, but then on the local host http://127.0.0.1:4567/ it showed "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty."

Comment: In addition to sethi's suggestion, your `config.ru` needs to run the new class, and not `Sinatra::Application` directly . . .

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I got it working with config.ru

Comment: See http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Sinatra::Base%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps

Comment: @mbratch I think you're right. I've put in a vote to close this, feel free to add your vote.